# Create a DIV tag that does not reload across web pages

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I am trying to create a div at the top of my page that does not reload itself as users browse through my website. The div will contain an MP3 player that will play constantly across the site. How would I go about coding this to work in such a manner?

The main site is running joomla, I would like to avoid using Iframes as the site needs to remain search engine friendly.

```
<div id="siteWidePlayer">
 <audio controls>
  <source src="audiostream.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="audiostream" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
 </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Basically, what you want is for the top frame to persist when navigating through the site. Take a look into iframes and/or client side methodologies for loading new data through AJAX requests.

Comment: As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for [so]. Recommendation questions like these tend to become outdated and don't really "make the internet a better place". Find out exactly what functionality you want (it's not related to soundcloud or an audio player), then you can be more specific in your requests.

Comment: OK I shall edit and reword the question :)

Comment: Go for it! :) Don't worry if the question gets closed in the mean time - it can always be opened again.

Comment: That's a great edit! If there is any code that you have written to attempt to solve this, it would be great if you could post it as well. Even if it is pseudo-code it will show the community that some research effort was put into this before posting.

Comment: Sure this I have coded the div and what it contains

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this that doesn't involve changing the way your website navigation works. If you don't want the div to refresh, then you're going to have to not refresh the page. The only way to do that is to make your website navigation work through either ajax or iframes, both of which need special attention to keep SEO working well.

Comment: How do websites like soundcloud and beatport do it then, you can clearly see the url change?

Comment: Just because the url changed doesn't mean the page reloaded. :) Look into the history api. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1):

Use an Iframe to hold the body of your site.  Have the main layout of your site hold the top div and have a div for the iframe.  This way your top div will be static.

Comment: Iframes just seem such dated technology, and are not search engine friendly, im hoping there is a better way to do this?

Comment: @WebblyBrown Yes, you could do 100% of your site navigation using ajax, effectively turning it into a single page application.

Comment: @WebblyBrown - you should look into loading HTML content though AJAX calls - this way you don't need to redirect users to a new page in order to display new content to them.

Comment: He sure could, but that may not be the simplest implementation.  Without knowing more requirements its hard to say that SPA is the way to go.

Comment: Ill add some more to the question guys to clear up a bit more sorry about this

Comment: it's the... only way to go. The only way to not refresh the div is to not refresh the page.

Comment: Not true, you can refresh the iframe as much as you want without refreshing the page.

Comment: Right, but that's exactly what i'm saying. It's a single page. you aren't refreshing the page, therefore it isn't refreshing the div.

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to load content into a div that will contain your non-static content.

```
<div id="siteWidePlayer">
    <audio controls>
    <source src="audiostream.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="audiostream" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
<div id="content">
    // Your default content here
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(someElement).on(someEvent, function() {
            $('#content').load(somePage);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Edit:

Ajax can remain SOE friendly by using hashbangs(#!) which are outdated, but supported by older browsers and major search engines or through pushState calls which are standard, but not supported by older browsers(IE8, etc.). [Google has a good article on this matter.](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seems the way I need to do this then is with AJAX, thats what I was trying to establish :)

Answer (score 0):

in order to this you have 3 ways:

1- the very first solution is using iframe which as you have said is not your favorite solution.

2- create a plugin for your browser, which is not a good way cause your end-users will be forced to install it, but for you SEO concern this is the best.

3- Change the way you load your pages and use jQuery load function to load you actual pages, to do so you have to Create a new html page with jQuery in it, create your div element with your data at the top of your page and create another div for your site pages to load, but this way your problem would be dealing with joomla to make sure all of you joomla pages and all the links and scripts in those pages are safe to be loaded this way. try this as an example:

```
jQuery('#question-header').load('http://stackoverflow.com/', function(){
    //Your callback to-dos
})
```

this will load the stackoverflow homepage right through this very page in question-header box at the top of this page.

at the end if I were you I would definitely use iframe because of fewer risks that I'll have to take.