# How do I force HTML5 audio to play throughout the entire site?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm currently building a website for a client.

My client wants a specific song to play throughout the entire website (I have the MP3 & OGG audio files locally) however, when I go onto another page the music will play from the beginning.

```
<div id="music">
   <audio  controls loop autoplay>
     <source src="audio/oud.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
     <source src="audio/oud.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
     Your phone does not support the audio element.
   </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Convince the client that's not good, and will cause people not to visit their site.

Comment: Playing uncontrollable music in the background of a site is a huge user experience problem.

Comment: You have to use AJAX:

Maybe this?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20405373/1919749

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this, you will have to do one of two things:

1. Create a single page application (this is the cleaner solution),
   or
2. Create a page with an iframe that wraps the entire site and
   play the file in the main file

However, I would very much caution against doing what you are doing, it is an accessibility violation to play audio automatically for more than 3 seconds without the ability to turn it off and it will be an irritation to any blind or visually impaired users who visit the site using a screen reader.

Comment: It would be an irritation to just about everybody. It would be a barrier to anyone dependant on a screen reader.

Comment: Trust me, I've told my client numerous times that having audio is a terrible idea but they insist that "it's part of the culture". I just want this project done as soon as possible! :/